# Angular View Showing Wrong Result

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm having a serious issue with an Angular lesson in Codecademy. I'm not sure if there is a bug in the program running Codecademy or if there is a mistake in my code. I should be seeing this H1 heading, **This Month's Bestsellers** in addition to all the images of the books. However, instead I'm seeing this result: **`{{title}}`** along with this message: **"Oops! The test returned an error. Maybe you have a syntax error, or a typo. See full error. Why am I seeing `{{title}}`, which is html code, being displayed on the screen? I can't seem to find out why!

This is the `html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
      <link href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500,300,700,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Book End</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="main" ng-controller="MainController">
      <div class="container">

        <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
        <h2>{{ promo }}</h2>

        <div ng-repeat="product in products" class="col-md-6"> 
                <div class="thumbnail"> 
                    <img ng-src="{{ product.cover }}"> 
                    <p class="title">{{ product.name }}</p> 
                    <p class="price">{{ product.price | currency }}</p> 
                    <p class="date">{{ product.pubdate | date }}</p> 
                </div> 
                </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <h2>Available for iPhone and Android.</h2>
        <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/shutterbugg/app-store.png" width="120px" />
        <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/shutterbugg/google-play.png" width="110px" />
      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Modules -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    <!-- Controllers -->
    <script src="js/controllers/MainController.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the JavaScript (MainController.js):

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) { 
  $scope.title = 'This Month\'s Bestsellers'; 
  $scope.promo = 'The most popular books this month.';
  $scope.products = [
    { 
        name: 'The Book of Trees', 
        price: 19, 
        pubdate: new Date('2014', '03', '08'), 
        cover: 'img/the-book-of-trees.jpg' 
    }, 
    { 
        name: 'Program or be Programmed', 
        price: 8, 
        pubdate: new Date('2013', '08', '01'), 
        cover: 'img/program-or-be-programmed.jpg' 
    }, 
    **{
    name: 'One Simple Idea',
    price: 22,
    pubdate: new Date('2011', '02' '18'),
    cover: "https://s1.postimg.org/36xiodlmzz/Key-1259589676_3_D.jpg"
   },
{
    name: 'Sell Your Idea with or without a Patent',
    price: 22,
    pubdate: new Date('2015', '03','03'),
    cover:"https://s1.postimg.org/4vjmzpyxa7/stephen-key-book.jpg" 
   },
      ]
}]);
```

This is the code that I added:

```
{
    name: 'One Simple Idea',
    price: 22,
    pubdate: new Date('2011', '02' '18'),
    cover: "https://s1.postimg.org/36xiodlmzz/Key-1259589676_3_D.jpg"
   },
{
    name: 'Sell Your Idea with or without a Patent',
    price: 22,
    pubdate: new Date('2015', '03','03'),
    cover:"https://s1.postimg.org/4vjmzpyxa7/stephen-key-book.jpg" 
   },
```

**This code is in the exact same syntax as the code that immediately precedes it.** However, when I remove the code I put in, and leave the original code, everything is ok. **See and compare pictures.**

[Screenshot of result of my additional code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvYZv.jpg)

[Screenshot of result without my code included](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3C9or.jpg)

Comment: What are `**` is your JSON object ?

Comment: Can you do F12 & check developer console for errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `,` in this line: `pubdate: new Date('2011', '02' '18')`. It should be `pubdate: new Date('2011', '02', '18')`.

Also, I suppose you added `**` to highlight the code in the question. If not, it should not be there in the code on your machine.
Here's a working example of your code: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prerak6962/ug9b2c5L/6/)

Comment: OMG! @Prerak Sola, thankyou so much! I can't believe that just a missing comma in the date caused such a big issue! Wow! Thanks so much man! You solved that issue fast! I need you as my Angular.js tutor haha....are you on Twitter?

Comment: Happy to help :)